# Double Header Bar on Careers Favorites Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

So I was browsing around Careers today and came upon this glorious bug:

[image: Double Header?]

Almost as good as double rainbows, but not really.

To reproduce:

1. Go to your favorites page (http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/favorites)
2. Click the "Your Favorites (xx)" link in the right column:

   [image: Favorites Link]
3. You should now have double headers.

I've also made a bug reproduction screencast at [Screencast.com](http://www.screencast.com/users/moore.alex/folders/Jing/media/add10c4f-02cb-4035-8802-5d30a3cbfb30).

I can reproduce in Chrome / Firefox on OSX 10.8.

Comment: Just  when we thought we had taken care of all of those ... fix coming shortly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No exceptions for you, "favorites" page: AJAX responses are only allowed to send partial views.

Should be fixed now.